# Not getting any data in POST request in views django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to get a value from a select option in django view but not getting any value in post request:

my HTML looks like

```
<form method="post">
<select class="custom-select" title="region_list" value="{{ region }}">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>

      {% for i in region_id %}
          <li><option value="{{ i.region }}">{{ forloop.counter }}. {{ i.region }}</option></li>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and my view file looks like :

```
class updateOrderType(View):
    template_view = 'admin/custom_orders_all.html'

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        region_id = list(UserRegionMapping.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).values_list('region_id', flat=True))
        store_list=list(StoreRegionMapping.objects.filter(region__id__in=region_id).values_list('store_id__name', flat=True))
        region_name = UserRegionMapping.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)


        # store_id=Order.objects.filter(id=ixd).values_list('store_id')
        return render(request, self.template_view, {'region_id': region_name, 'store_list':store_list})

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):
        data=request.POST
```

in this I'm not getting any data in "data=request.POST".

Comment: you haven't specified the action in the html form

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi tried that, its still giving me an empty queryset. '''<form action ="."method="post">''' is what i tried

Comment: and you are putting `<option>` in `<li>` tag which you shouldn't

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi still getting same answer

Comment: Solved it!! It was a very silly mistake, forgot to add "name="xyz" in my select class"
after adding it looks like 
"<select class="custom-select" title="region_list" value="{{ region }}" name="region">"